# How to edit values in wicket table

Tags: java, wicket

I created form with editable table and submit button:

```
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final Item<Game> listItem) {
                final Game game = listItem.getModelObject();
                listItem.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Game>(game));
                listItem.add(new TextField("players", Model.of(game.getPlayerResult().getPlayer().getName() + ":"
                        + game.getOpponent().getPlayer().getName())));
                listItem.add(new TextField("leftSide", Model.of(game.getResult().getLeftSide())));
                listItem.add(new TextField("rightSide", Model.of(game.getResult().getRightSide())));
                listItem.add(new CheckBox("overtime", Model.of(game.getResult().getOvertime())));

            }
```

now I want to save new value which I insert but when I call:

```
       add(new Button("submit") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {

                Iterator<Item<Game>> a = dataView.getItems();
                while (a.hasNext()) {
                    Game game = a.next().getModelObject();     
                        System.out.println(game.getPlayerResult().getPlayer().getName());
                }
                setResponsePage(new SchedulePage(tournament, table));
            }
        });
```

it prints still old value. So how I can get table with new values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing it, the text fields cannot write back the values into your domain objects.

Learn about models then use the appropriate one:

```
listItem.add(new TextField("rightSide", new PropertyModel(game, "result.rightSide")));
```

There are many other options, e.g. [safemodel](https://github.com/duesenklipper/wicket-safemodel).